# Cookie set without HttpOnly flag

Tags: wp-config, cookies

I try to add cookie information but i have no result. The tool sends me the same information. I trying to displayed the mention HttpOnly after path

```
parameter => "Parameter : PHPSESSID=jndfbcev6hie1jm02btk19grs1; path=/ "
```

I've configured WP with those options without succes:

```
@ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', true); 
@ini_set('session.cookie_secure', true); 
@ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', true);
```

and modified the header and the htaccess ! nothing run !

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding

```
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HttpOnly"
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; Secure"
```

to your .htaccess?

Found this on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129201/add-secure-and-httponly-flags-to-every-set-cookie-response-in-apache-httpd)